# In IdentityServer3 scope is required for resource owner flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I've tried to request a token without scope using resource owner flow but got "invalid_scope". Why IdentityServer3 require scope for this flow when OAuth spec says that it is optional?

Comment: Because that's how we implemented it. Use IS4 to get rid of this constraint.

Comment: Thanks! That was my first thought but wasn't sure. Now got confirmed by the source ;-)